# DataTables jQuery plugin : sort and pagination disabled when mixed with vue.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have very simple example of DataTables jQuery plugin with a simple javascript source that is rendered before a basic Vue.js binding:

JavaScript:

```
           var aDemoItems =[
            {
                "name":       "Tiger Nixon",
                "position":   "System Architect",
                "salary":     "$3,120",
                "start_date": "2011/04/25",
                "office":     "Edinburgh",
                "extn":       "5421"
            },
            {
                "name":       "Garrett Winters",
                "position":   "Director",
                "salary":     "$5,300",
                "start_date": "2011/07/25",
                "office":     "Edinburgh",
                "extn":       "8422"
            },
            {
                "name":       "Vivou fou",
                "position":   "Lazy nephew",
                "salary":     "$7,300",
                "start_date": "2010/04/22",
                "office":     "Edinburgh",
                "extn":       "8422"
            }
        ]

        $('#missionTable').DataTable({
                            data: aDemoItems,
                            columns: [
                                { data: 'name' },
                                { data: 'position' },
                                { data: 'salary' },
                                { data: 'office' }
                            ]
                        });

 var app = new Vue({
                    el: '#app',
                    data: {
                        name: packageName,
                        path: packagePath,
                        data: missionsData
                    }
                })
```

HTML:

```
        <table id="missionTable" class="display" width="100%"></table>
```

It seams to work but search, sorting, nb item display and pagination are disabled if Is use vue.js in spite of no error appears in console
[image]

Do you know  what is wrong and how use Datatable and vue.js at same time?

Comment: When i run your code, everything is working just fine for me. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MxvGLq

Comment: Check your console log, if the codepen test of @CarstenLøvboAndersen works, you have an error in an other library.

Comment: @Baro if you are talking about the missing svg error in the console log, then I don't see how this is relevant to the question or the comment.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen ok thank you error was to use Vue.js after jqery Datatable, it seems to cause issues to table features , in spite of there is no logs in console, I will change question cause it can be interesting

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen You misunderstood me, I told Lemec Cinq to check the logs.